# Find all application tiers for a given TFS instance

Tags: team-foundation-server

Do you know a way to list all application tier servers for a TFS instance? It's probably somewhere in the `Tfs_Configuration` database, but I didn't find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to one of the AppTier's and open the TFS configuration console you will get a list on the Application Tier panel.

It will list all servers use in the last thirty days.